# CSS & JS - Update position while searching

Tags: javascript, css, html

I made a grid, in which the user can search and, if one of the elements have the searched word, or at least a part of it, in the custom "search" tag that all the searchable elements have, the elements will be set to hidden or visible.

To understand better, please test it out [here](https://picoral2.websiteseguro.com/grid.html).

What I would like to do but don't now how yet it's update the positions of the elements, so they just don't disappear.

Can someone give a "north" on how to do that?

Code:

- [Full Code](https://pastebin.com/0JBJ5sBs)
- [Only JS](https://pastebin.com/cEvterA3)
- [Only CSS](https://pastebin.com/0j7jUZNK)
- [Only HTML](https://pastebin.com/iNVUnjcg)

Comment: Position the elements relatively and remove the absolute styling. It will automatically display the items as per your need.

Comment: Why not you are just putting the opacity 0 on that item you don't want to show ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need each `.game` to remain in the document flow so you should avoid absolute positioning in this case.

Take some time to learn about modern layout techniques such as flexbox and grid. Avoid styling with id selectors and instead write your styles with reusable classes.

```js
function searchGames() {
  var input, filter, i, searchables; //Variables
  input = document.getElementById("search-bar"); //Get Search-Box
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); //Get Searched Word
  searchables = document.querySelectorAll('[search]'); //Get a NodeList of all nodes with the tag "search=*"

  //Turns the NodeList into an array (array)
  var array = [];
  for (var index = searchables.length; index--; array.unshift(searchables[index]));

  //Puts all the searchable names in an array
  var names = []; //Array with all searchable names (search tag) - Dic Values
  var ids = []; //ID's of searchable itens. In the same order of the names - Dic Keys
  var games = {}; //Dictionay with ID as key and searchable name as value
  for (i = 0; i < searchables.length; i++) {
    var name = array[i].attributes[2].value;
    var id = array[i].attributes[0].value;
    names.push(name);
    ids.push(id);
  }

  //Adds the keys e value to the dic "games"
  ids.forEach((key, i) => games[key] = names[i]);

  //Search Method
  for (i = 0; i < searchables.length; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById(ids[i]); //Get the elements to hide/show
    var text = names[i]; //Get the searchable name
    text = text.toUpperCase() //Disables case sensitive

    console.log(text)
    //Check if the filter matches a searchable name
    //TODO: Update position. Now it only hides the element
    if (text.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      //Allows the element to be visible
      div.style.display = "";
    } else {
      //Hides the element 
      div.style.display = "none";
    }

  }

}
```

```css
:root {
  --games-blur: 3px;
  --games-width: 150px;
  --play-btn-width: 40px;
}

.gameslist {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.play_btn {
  height: var(--play-btn-width);
  width: var(--play-btn-width);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.games {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: var(--games-width);
  width: var(--games-width);
  transition: all 0.03s ease-in-out;
}

.games:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  filter: blur(var(--games-blur));
}

.games:hover .play_btn {
  visibility: visible;
}

#search-bar {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png");
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #5e9fd7;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-bar" onkeyup="searchGames()" placeholder="Procurar" />

<div class="gameslist">
  <div id="pong" class="games" search="pong"><img class="play_btn" src="https://i.imgur.com/lFDDBjz.png" /></div>
  <div id="fut-mesa" class="games" search="futebol de mesa"><img class="play_btn" src="https://i.imgur.com/lFDDBjz.png" /></div>
  <div id="forca" class="games" search="forca"><img class="play_btn" src="https://i.imgur.com/lFDDBjz.png" /></div>
  <div id="dama" class="games" search="damas"><img class="play_btn" src="https://i.imgur.com/lFDDBjz.png" /></div>
  <div id="pacman" class="games" search="pacman"><img class="play_btn" src="https://i.imgur.com/lFDDBjz.png" /></div>
  <div id="quick-math" class="games" search="quick math"><img class="play_btn" src="https://i.imgur.com/lFDDBjz.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that I couldn't figure out in this new way was how not blur the play button when hovering, only the background